# Magneto: Adding configurable product to cart fails : Please specify the product's option(s)

Tags: java, php, api, magento, xml-rpc

Using Magento 1.7.0.2

I'm able to add simple products to the cart with out any problem.
But when I'm trying to add configurable product to the cart it throws following XmlRpcException.

```
org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Please specify the product's option(s).
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:197)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:156)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)
```

API documentation for this xml-rpc call http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html

Magento API doc wasn't much helpful. So followed the advise given at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19925338/12641.

Here is the method arguments to the XML-RPC call

```
[25f6d3a4606a18d24cdeb7ad6ad58a, cart_product.add, [25, [{product_id=126, quantity=2, options=[[{value=1, key=862}], [{value=65, key=501}], [{value=1, key=526}], [{value=100, key=525}], [{value=1, key=274}], [{value=1, key=273}]]}]]]
```

I'm still receiving the `org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Please specify the product's option(s).` error in the console.

I interested to know how to add configurable product to cart, when it has required options to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the Magento php code I've realized Magento is expecting "super_attribute" instead of "options" key.

Here is the Java array I'm passing to add custom product with super attributes

```
[
  8bd5ea08fc5c6f5d17445f10db593d4f, 
  cart_product.add, 
  [
    51, 
    [
      {
        product_id=3051, 
        super_attribute={
          272=22, 
          525=100
        }, 
        quantity=2
      }
    ]
  ]
]
```

With these call parameters I was able to add product to cart.

From Magneto Admin console, I know which super attributes needs to be passed as super attributes.

But how do I get these super attributes for a custom product through Magento XML-RPC/SOAP api?

In PHP to get the super attributes here is what I found people were using.

```
$productAttributeOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
```

I can't use this code because, I'm dependent on API only to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.